# Event handler not working - Lost Focus event on Popup

Tags: c#, .net, windows-phone-8.1

I'm trying to close a popup when it loses focus (i.e. user taps somewhere outside the popup)

in my MainPage I have this

```
    Popup p;
    public MainPage()
    {
        this.InitializeComponent();
        this.NavigationCacheMode = NavigationCacheMode.Required;
        p = new Popup();
        p.LostFocus += new RoutedEventHandler(p_LostFocus);
    }
```

And my lost focus event is this

```
    void p_LostFocus(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        p.IsOpen = false;
    }
```

When I tap outside the popup nothing happens, it doesn't even execute the p_lostFocus method.  Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `Popup` control is rendered on top of all other controls. It seems that while the `Popup` is open, the other controls can't get focus, so the `Popup` can't *lose* its focus. (The reason for this might be that `Popup` controls are assigned a unique window handle, instead of being rendered as part of the page as all other controls - at least this is the case in WPF. Please correct me if I'm wrong...).

Anyway, if you just want to close the `Popup` when tapping somewhere else, you only need to ensure that the popup's `IsLightDismissEnabled` property is set to `true`, either in XAML code:

```
<Popup IsLightDismissEnabled="True" ...>
```

or in C# code:

```
p.IsLightDismissEnabled = true;
```

When choosing the second option, you can set it anytime after instantiating the `Popup` and, when setting it within the page's constructor, after the call to `InitializeComponent()`, for example:

```
p = new Popup();
p.IsLightDismissEnabled = true;
```

In this case, you won't need the `LostFocus` event at all.

If you like to perform additional operations after closing the popup, register to its `Closed` event instead of the `LostFocus` event.

Comment: Please note that why you think adding your code might be useful ;).

Comment: where do I add this?  I tried adding to MainPage constructor and it is behaving erratically

Comment: I think the intent is for it to be added to the event handler.